Probability Distribution Underlying Ngram Model
Texts introducing ngram models often directly manipulate conditional probabilities. For example, given a corpus $V$ with a bigram model on its words, we would compute the probability of a sentence $W_1 W_2 ... W_n$ as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(W_1W_2...W_n) &= P(W_1)P(W_2|W_1)P(W_3|W_1W_2)...P(W_n|W_1...W_{n-1}) \\
&\approx P(W_1)P(W_2|W_1)P(W_3|W_2)...P(W_n|W_{n-1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then, most texts would calculate $P(W_a|W_b)$ as simply $count(W_aW_b)/count(W_b)$, and they would skirt around the marginal probability computation of $P(W_1)$ by simply using a start token $P(W_1) = P(W_1|\text{<s>})$.
But what is the actual probability distribution underlying such a model? How would we actually calculate the marginal probabilities $P(W)$? And when we speak of "the probability of a sentence", is it compared to the probability of all possible sentences formed by all combinations of the words in the corpus?

The marginal probability $P(W)$ of a word $W$ is the sum of probabilities of all sentences of the vocabulary in which $W$ appears across all positions, thus intuitively common words which usually appear anywhere in a sentence like "is" have larger marginal probabilities than those of rare words or words which don't usually appear in arbitrary position in a sentence like "vein".
However, directly calculating $P(W)$ is infeasible because the number of all possible valid sentences of a vocabulary are extremely large or infinite for a non-fixed length language model. For practical purposes, $P(W)$ is often approximated using the corpus statistics through the relative frequency of observed word $W$ count and total words count in the corpus, under the assumption that the corpus is representative of the true distribution.
Similarly the frequency (probability) of a sentence is measured against all possible sentences of the vocabulary. Since again the number of all possible valid sentences is nearly infinite, n-gram language models restrict their practical computation to observed sentences in the corpus. This ensures the model remains practical while still assigning probabilities in a way that approximates the true distribution.

There's something here that still doesn't make sense to me. From Bayes' Theorem, $P(W_2|W_1) = P(W_1W_2) / P(W_1)$. By the approximate definitions given in your last paragraph, this is equal to $[ count(W1W2) / \text{num_sentences} ] / [ count(W_1) / \text{num_words} ]$. This seems incorrect (intuitively, the correct probability should be $count(W1W2) / count(W_1)$. So it would seem to me that both $P(W_1W_2)$ and $P(W_1)$ should have the same denominator; would this denominator be the sum of all 1-, 2-, ..., n-grams in the corpus?

I believe you misunderstand my last paragraph, my 'frequency' mentioned there is synonymous with probability a la frequentist and I only assume bi-gram model following your scope here. Your practical frequency formula is correct. Hope now clarifies.

Ok then I am still confused: (1) do you agree that $P(W_2|W_1) = count(W_1W_2) / count(W_1)$ ? (2) under the approximations you mention, what would be your calculations for $P(W_1 W_2)$ and for $P(W_1)$ ?

The gist here is true probabilities are infeasible to obtain as my answer explained, so we have to approximate them using corpus statistics via these counts. Hope now clarifies.

Ok, I see now. So $P(W_1 W_2)$ would be calculated as $P(W_1) P(W_2|W_2)$ = $[count(W_1) / \text{num_words}] [count(W_1W_2) / count(W_1)]$ = $count(W_1W_2) / \text{num_words}$ under a bigram model. Thank you very much for clarifying!

One more question- under this calculation, $P(W_1 W_2) = count(W_1 W_2) / \text{num_words}$ for all $W_1$, $W_2$. However, this seems to be an improper distribution? For example, if the corpus is "foo bar baz", then we have: P(foo bar) = 1/3, P(foo baz) = 0, P(bar baz) = 1/3, P(bar foo) = 0, P(baz foo) = 0, P(baz bar) = 0, and P(W1 W2) = 0 for all other word combinations. This adds to 2/3 and not 1?

This last approximation expressed in your last comment is not entirely correct. You should only use the Markov chain rule to compute the approximation. Note $W_1W_2$ are just 2-word arbitrary sequence which may not be a sentence in general, so my answer doesn't discuss them at all, you cannot simply divide by the same $\text{num_words}$ like for one-word marginal $P(W_1)$. If you really need to use $count(W_1W_2)$ as numerator, then apparently you have to count all 2-word pairs in the corpus, not all 1-word! Since n-gram model is assumed, you should stick to the Markov version approximation.

I understand what you're saying, but it seems like then that the Markov approximation is not defining a proper joint probability distribution over the words. Anyways, I think this warrants a separate question so I will ask it in a new question--feel free to continue the discussion there. Your comments have been invaluable and have cleared up many things for me. Thank you!
